# how and what is XCODE's Bundle ID, signing?

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle-identifier

sorry new to IOS programming. must i enroll to apple developer program to obtain a bundle id ?

apparently i am trying to start my first project, but it seems like i need to choose a bundle idnentifier so that the signing tab would have no errors.

is the signing tab required for me to make a development environment on my device ?

Answer (score 4):

Bundle identifier is on which uniquely identifies your app on app store, it is unique & hence 2 apps can't have the same bundle identifier's.

Example of a bundle id
com.azhar.calulator seems like this.

Signing of a code is required for running, testing & debugging of the app.It requires provisioning profiles and its certificates.

Procedure for getting them:

1.Run Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, or Safari.

2.In the iOS Dev Center, click Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.

3.In the drop-down menu in the top left corner, verify that iOS, tvOS, watchOS is selected.

4.In the left-hand sidebar, select Provisioning Profiles → Development.
Click +.

5.Select iOS App Development and click Continue.

6.Select an App ID to associate with the provisioning profile and click Continue.

7.To be able to use one development provisioning profile across multiple apps, select a wildcard App ID, if available.

8.Select one or more certificates for development to include in the provisioning profile and click Continue.

9.Only certificates for development are listed.

10.Select one or more devices to include in the provisioning profile and click Continue.

11.Provide a name for the profile and click Continue.

12.(Optional) Click Download to download the provisioning profile.

13.Click Done.

Comment: What and where is the iOS Dev Center? How do I get to it?

Answer (score 2):

The bundle ID is your application ID. It is the one you set when creating the project, and should look something like: com.darkArtistry.appName

What you need from the Apple Developer Program is :
 1 - A valid developer to certificate to sign your application
 2 - A valid provisioning profile, that matches your appID.

Provisioning profiles allow wildcards in some cases like com.darkArtistry.* so they can match more than one bundle ID.

I would recommend you to first get your certificate from the developer program, and then xCode will help you creating a provisioning profile for you.

There are a lot of guides out there, let us know when you are exactly stuck.